# Can I recover MySQL data if the .MYD file is missing?

Tags: mysql

One of my databases got corrupted. All of the tables are stored using MyISAM engine. I managed to grab what's left in the server's `mysql\data` folder. All the `ib*` files are intact.

As for the tables, for those that have `.frm`, `.MYD` and `.MYI` files, I can dump them. I used `innodb_force_recovery` in order to start the database before dumping them into .sql files.

However there are tables that are missing `.MYD` and `.MYI` files, so only `.frm` files are left. As I understand it, for tables created using MyISAM engine, `.MYD` contains the table's data. Is there any way to recover data from these tables or is it impossible to do?

Comment: Yes, the .MYD is the only place data for a MyISAM table is stored.  Are you sure it was MyISAM?  What other evidence (SHOW TABLE STATUS, error messages, etc)?

Comment: flagged for movement to dba, please do the same and do not delete the question so it will be linked. if you deleted it restore from backup

Answer (score 1):

You can't restore data from the `.frm` files. That file only contains the table metadata — i.e. column names and types, and so on. No data.

The `.MYD` contained the data. The `.MYI` contained the indexes on that data. Indexes can be rebuilt from data, but the data cannot be reconstructed from the table definition alone.

If you had a recent backup of your database, that's the only place you will get the data from.

If you don't have a backup, then you're out of luck. The only thing you have is a costly lesson in the importance of making backups.